# 8007064c(2011) and 80280007(2009) persistant after all known repairs

Tags: windows-live-messenger

I'm on Windows 7 Home x64, and have ran into a major issue with Live Messenger(which I use daily).

I have full offline installers for both 2011 and the last Wave 3 2009(14.0.8117.0416) Suites. Both give the following errors:

Live Essentials 2011 Offline installer(official):

> An unknown error occured.
>   Error:0x8007064c Source WLXSuite

WL 2009 offline installer(official):

> You already have a more recent version
>   of Windows Live.
>
> Error:  OnCatalogResult:0x80280007
>
> Next steps:  If you want to install
>   this older version, first uninstall
>                any later versions that are on your computer.
>
> Get help with this error

The 2011 installer also says it is updating messenger, I don't select anything else. Then last 2009 installer says their is a newer version that needs uninstalled even after the following procedures.

1. MS Help pages provided all basically lead to using uninstall from control panel. Which I've uninstalled all Live components including watcom safety scanner and portable SQL from.
2. I've followed online instructions for manually deleting folders from Program Files(x86), Appdata, and some others under \User\All Users and the one for the one account on the machine.
3. I've used CCcleaner 3.01, ASC 3.7.3 and Beta 4 with deep scan along with deleting folders, and checked their uninstallers for Live components too, and none were there.
4. wlmuninstaller.exe tool reports nothing, but after a failed install it finds something, but failes to clean it under all user admin privilege.

The same errors still occur after all of that. Google searching I see people on forums suggesting reinstalling the OS cause MS doesn't even know how to fix this, but I'm hoping someone here can help.

**NOTE**: I don't have System Restore or any other state freeze utilities going, and I don't have any real time AV going(I sometime scan with defender, anti rootkits, and online scanners).

**NOTE2**:I posted this on windowslivehelp.com, before looking to see if the place was active or not, hoping I can get help here.

Thanks

Comment: Did you see this thread?...http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7programs/thread/9217f167-f28b-41eb-a876-d7b7eec7f525

Answer (score 1):

Problem found and fixed..registry keys were being written that didn't contain ACLs..This is why no reg tools can even detect the keys..Users will have to manual set owner and admin perms to delete them, no software outside kernel mode can fix this when it happens.. If regedit wasn't broken I wouldn't of been able to..

It DOES take a wipe if wiping dozens of keys after setting each ones perms isn't practical to the user..I won't bother posting logs, I've looked and they'd just lead to more questions..

example key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\A49B6681220C2EA49826913B104EE03B\2FFAE75BEE6DC6C41957DEF971FB1CCB

No tool could even detect it, even MS's own registry ACL dumper.. it didn't even have a owner..